# PHP connection variables ini file

Tags: php, mysqli, ini

What are the risks and benefits of storing DB connection info in the ini file, if the only purpose of accessing the database remotely is to SELECT?

Comment: What *the* ini file? The `php.ini` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with storing configuration in *an* ini file, but you'd be better off not touching *the* php.ini file.

Just create your own .ini file and read it using `parse_ini_file($filename)` or `parse_ini_file($filename, true)` to group by sections as well.

For more information, refer to the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

**EDIT**

Further example

```
; This is your 'config.ini' file, stored on your web server
; Just make sure it isn't in a public directory!

[database]
host = localhost
user = bob
password = password
```

Then your php:

```
$config = parse_ini_file(__DIR__ . '/../config.ini', true); // Assuming your php is in the root directory of your web server, so placing the file where it can't be seen by prying eyes!
$host = $config['database']['host'];
// etc...
```

Comment: I am on a shared host, so I don't think it is THE ini file anyway. I just meant, the one my website uses.

Comment: Wait, the purpose of using the ini file is partially to not have the configuration information inside the root. How does it help to create another one if my username and password will still be floating around in the clear?

Comment: See the edit I've just added. It's important to place any configuration file outside of your public web directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant `php.ini` file and settings under `[mysqli]` section:

```
[mysqli]
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_host = 127.0.0.1
mysqli.default_user = db_user
mysqli.default_pw = db_pass
```

then setting them in ini file makes further use of myqsli convenient, since you don't have to parse any file / define your own config, simply connect:

```
$db = mysqli_connect(); // no arguments, just works.
$res = mysqli_query($db, 'SHOW DATABASES');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Risk only exists if you left phpinfo somewhere, then you username and password will be exposed to anyone viewing this file.

Comment: What do you mean, "left phpinfo somewhere?"

Comment: file with `phpinfo();` inside to check current php settings (ie: in phpmyadmin you can view phpinfo page if you enable it in it's config)

Comment: Oh I see, so you mean as long as none of my php files execute phpinfo();, it should be okay? What do you recommend if I am on a shared host?